# How to use language’s parser to get the tokens to populate the completion list in VS SDK?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

[Environment]：VS2017+C#

I want to extend Intellisense, just reorder completion list.
I read this doc:[Walkthrough: Displaying Statement Completion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2/%22Walkthrough:%20Displaying%20Statement%20Completion%22)

Doc say:

> The completion source is responsible for collecting the set of identifiers and adding the content to the completion window when a user types a completion trigger, such as the first letters of an identifier. In this example, the identifiers and their descriptions are **hard-coded** in the AugmentCompletionSession method. In most real-world uses, you would use your **language’s parser to get the tokens to populate the completion list**.

```
 void ICompletionSource.AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets)
{
    List<string> strList = new List<string>();
    strList.Add("addition");    // ☹HARD CODED !!!
    strList.Add("adaptation");
    strList.Add("subtraction");
    strList.Add("summation");
    m_compList = new List<Completion>();
    foreach (string str in strList)
        m_compList.Add(new Completion(str, str, str, null, null));

    completionSets.Add(new CompletionSet(
        "Tokens",    //the non-localized title of the tab
        "Tokens",    //the display title of the tab
        FindTokenSpanAtPosition(session.GetTriggerPoint(m_textBuffer),
            session),
        m_compList,
        null));
}   }
```

So, how to use **language’s parser to get the tokens to populate the completion list**? I need get default completion list then reorder it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the document is trying to say that that they've hard-coded the list of tokens to make the example easier to understand and that in real life you would have to do something much more complicated.

Exactly what you would have to do would depend on many things including what language you were trying to process.  For example, if you were trying to extend Intellisense for C# or Visual Basic you might use [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) to parse the source in your project as a way of creating a list of tokens you could use to build the completion list.

If you were working with some other language you would have to find (or create) a tool that could parse the language you were working with.

Comment: how to use Roslyn to get completion list?have some example?

Comment: OR, Can I get the complete list of VS self?